# Configure webpack for React to use multuple entries and outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to config the server to have multiple entries and outputs. The app is using Zurb Foundation,jquery and React.

I want jquery and foundation not to be part of the bundle.js and also to have a separate bundle for react

Webpack validates, server starts but nothing is show and in console appears: "ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined"

With a single entry is working, I don't know were is the error when trying to use multiple ones.

**webpack.config**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require('./node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: ['script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
        './dist/app.js' ],
        react: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },
     externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin('react', 'react.bundle.js')
    ],
    output: {
        filename: bundle.js'
        },

    devServer: {

        inline: true,
        contentBase: './build',
        port: 3000
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            },
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
          }
        ]
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "author": "CBM",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "mocha": "^3.1.0",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

**babel.rc**

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify an output for each entry:

```
entry: {
    jquery: ['script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js' ],
    bundle: './dist/app.js',
    react: ['react', 'react-dom']
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
}
```

If you want to add jquery and foundation libraries directly to the html just don't add the entries.
font: https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html